# Using K-means with RDF files

Tags: cluster-analysis, rdf, k-means, numerical

I have a set of RDF triplets and I want to put them in clusters using K-Means, but I don't know how to represent words by numerical values
for example: I have 3 triplets like

```
<'name','isa','johan'>
<'name','isa','fred'>
<'sport','isa','football'>
```

How can I get distance between these triplets?

Comment: Ehm, obviously *dictionary encoding* is the way to encode categorical data. It's trivial, Google helps ...

Comment: Even then, what would be the distance function? And between what? The instances? That's what you have to define and implement

Comment: By the way, there is a lot of research regarding RDF clustering - most thing have already been done - again, Google etc. is your friend